Connection Between Random Walk, Binomial Distribution and Normal Distribution
I have always heard that the probability of a Random Walk being in any given place at any given time follows a Binomial Distribution, and in the long run this becomes a Normal Distribution - but I have never understood why exactly. Now, I am trying to do this myself as a learning exercise.
In my previous question (Deriving Properties of the Random Walk), I derived the general mean and variance of a Random Walk.
If we consider a generic random walk $X_t$:
$$
Y_n = \begin{cases}
+1 & \text{with probability } p \\
-1 & \text{with probability } 1-p
\end{cases}
$$
$$
X_t = \sum_{i=1}^t Y_i
$$
Using basic logic, we can define $k$ as the number of +1 steps. Then, the number of -1 steps must be $t-k$. The position $X_t$ can be written as:
$$
X_t = k - (t-k) = 2k - t
$$
Solving for $k$:
$$
k = \frac{t + X_t}{2}
$$
Now, the probability of any specific sequence with $k$ positive steps and $t-k$ negative steps is (this is just like a coin toss problem, in which we want to analyze the probability for obtaining a specific sequence):
$$
p^k (1-p)^{t-k}
$$
However, there are multiple ways to arrange $k$ positive steps in $t$ total steps. The number of such arrangements is given by the binomial coefficient (i.e. combinatorics):
$$
\binom{t}{k} = \frac{t!}{k!(t-k)!}
$$
Therefore, the probability of having exactly $k$ positive steps (and consequently, being at position $X_t = 2k - t$) is:
$$
P(X_t = 2k - t) = \binom{t}{k} p^k (1-p)^{t-k}
$$
Substituting $k = \frac{t + X_t}{2}$ from before:
$$
P(X_t = x) = \binom{t}{\frac{t+x}{2}} p^{\frac{t+x}{2}} (1-p)^{\frac{t-x}{2}}
$$
And this is looks like a binomial distribution.
I feel that some constraints are needed in the above distribution, but I am not sure what exactly. For instance, if $x$ is an even number that $t$ must also be an even number - and if $x$ is an odd number than $t$ must also be an even number.

Next, I want to show the connection between the above derivation of the Binomial Distribution and the Normal Distribution. After doing a bit of reading, I think there is a general relationship between the Binomial Distribution and the Normal Distribution, even outside of the Random Walk.
Earlier, I had derived the mean and variance  of a Random Walk (Deriving Properties of the Random Walk):
$$
\mu = E[X_n] = n(2p - 1)
$$
$$
\sigma^2 = Var(X_n) = 4np(1-p)
$$
A lot of these proofs indirectly use the Central Limit Theorem. Thus, if we define a Normalized Random Variable :
$$
Z = \frac{X_n - \mu}{\sigma} = \frac{X_n - n(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}
$$
Consider the moment-generating function (MGF) of our binomial distribution:
$$
M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}] = [pe^t + (1-p)e^{-t}]^n
$$
We can express the MGF of $Z$ in terms of the MGF of $X$:
$$M_Z(t) = E[e^{t\frac{X_n - n(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}}]$$
$$M_Z(t) = E[e^{\frac{tX_n}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}} \cdot e^{-\frac{tn(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}}]$$
$$M_Z(t) = e^{-\frac{tn(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}} \cdot E[e^{\frac{tX_n}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}}]$$
Define $u = \frac{t}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}$, we can rewrite this as:
$$M_Z(t) = e^{-\frac{tn(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}} \cdot E[e^{uX_n}]$$
The expectation $E[e^{uX_n}]$ is the definition of the MGF of $X_n$ evaluated at $u$. In other words, it's $M_X(u)$:
$$M_Z(t) = e^{-\frac{tn(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}} \cdot M_X(\frac{t}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}})$$
Substituting the MGF of $X$:
$$
M_Z(t) = e^{-t\frac{n(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}} [pe^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}} + (1-p)e^{-\frac{t}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}}]^n
$$
This part I tried to adapt from lecture notes online. Using the Taylor expansion of $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3)$:
$$
M_Z(t) = e^{-t\frac{n(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}} [p(1 + \frac{t}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}} + \frac{t^2}{8np(1-p)} + O(n^{-3/2})) + \\
(1-p)(1 - \frac{t}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}} + \frac{t^2}{8np(1-p)} + O(n^{-3/2}))]^n
$$
Simplify:
$$
M_Z(t) = e^{-t\frac{n(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}} [1 + (2p-1)\frac{t}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}} + \frac{t^2}{4np(1-p)} + O(n^{-3/2})]^n
$$
$$ (2p-1)\frac{t}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}} = (2p-1)\frac{t\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{4n^2p(1-p)}} = \frac{(2p-1)t\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{4p(1-p)}} $$
Use the fact that for large n, $(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n \approx e^x$:
$$
M_Z(t) = e^{-t\frac{n(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}} e^{(2p-1)\frac{t}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}}n + \frac{t^2}{4p(1-p)} + O(n^{-1/2})}
$$
Simplify:
$$
M_Z(t) = e^{\frac{t^2}{2} + O(n^{-1/2})}
$$
As n approaches infinity:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} M_Z(t) = e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}
$$
This is the moment-generating function of the standard normal distribution.
Thus, in my eyes, we can now make the following conclusions:
$$
Z = \frac{X_n - n(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)
$$
$$
X_n \xrightarrow{d} N(n(2p-1), 4np(1-p))
$$

Did I do OK here?

It is $P\left(\frac{X_t+t}2=k\right)= \binom{t}{k} p^k (1-p)^{t-k}$ for $k\in 0,1,2,3,\ldots, t$ which looks like a binomial distribution

$X_n \xrightarrow{d} N(n(2p-1), 4np(1-p))$ does not make sense as a limit distribution as $n\to \infty$  since you should not have $n$ on the right hand side.  Note that $X_n$ will still only take integer values, with its parity being the same as the parity of $n$, while a normal distribution has continuous support.  Your $\frac{X_n - n(2p-1)}{\sqrt{4np(1-p)}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$ makes more sense.

You could have saved some effort both for yourself and us by just applying the central limit theorem to $Y_n$.

@Henry: thank you for this valuable feedback ... I will try to incorporate this tomorrow
